# Can i send a error-map along with a response object in response? What is the proper way?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have a spring rest end point which accepts a user object and returns another userobject as response. My controller method looks like:

```
@PostMapping
public UserResponse createUser(@RequestBody UserDetailsRequestModel userDetails)
            throws Exception {
        
        UserRest userResponse= new UserRest();

        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        UserDto userDto = modelMapper.map(userDetails, UserDto.class);
        userDto.setRoles(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Roles.ROLE_USER.name())));
        UserDto createdUser = userService.createUser(userDto);
        returnValue = modelMapper.map(createdUser, UserResponse.class);

        return userResponse;
    }
```

My userResponse class looks like

```
public class UserRest {

    private String userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    ....getters and setters
```

And this flow is working fine. But now I need to add validation to createUser method (JSR 303) to check if incoming JSON fields are ok. For this I am trying to add below code in my controller

```
@PostMapping
    public UserResponse createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDetailsRequestModel userDetails, BindingResult result){

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            Map<String, String> errorMap = new HashMap<>();

            for(FieldError error: result.getFieldErrors()){
                errorMap.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
            }
            **return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>(errorMap, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);**
        }

        UserRest userResponse= new UserRest();

        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        UserDto userDto = modelMapper.map(userDetails, UserDto.class);
        userDto.setRoles(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Roles.ROLE_USER.name())));
        UserDto createdUser = userService.createUser(userDto);
        returnValue = modelMapper.map(createdUser, UserResponse.class);

        return **userResponse**;
```

The obvious problem in my code is that I can't convert from ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>> to UserResponse object.

Is there a proper way of doing this ? so that I can send errors(if any) or the UserResponse object if there are no errors within the same controller method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a type of ResponseEntity<?>

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDetailsRequestModel userDetails, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        ...
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorMap);
    }
    ...
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return an HttpEntity<?> generic object from a controller method accepting both response type.
You have to wrap the UserResponse response around a ResponseEntity object